# Cannot install 12.04.2

Tags: 12.04

I'm running XP and am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.2. The box is setup to boot from CD/DVD before the hard drive. It spins for a bit and then goes ahead and runs XP from the hard drive. I tried double-clicking "ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso" from within XP and it says "Windows cannot open this file:"

Help!

Comment: wait another week for 13.04 then.

Comment: Could you PLEASE provide more information? Specifically, tell us how you made the live-cd, what kind of computer you have/hardware details, describe your bios settings maybe. Tell us something more.

Comment: Make sure that you burn the CD/DVD at the slowest rate possible thus ensuring there are no problems with the disc. Once you have done that, restart your PC and go into the BIOS settings ensuring that CD Drive is checked first and foremost, save the settings, restart the pc, insert the disc and restart the pc.  You shouldn't get any problems now.

Comment: Do and [MD5USM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) on the downloaded ISO. Also try creating a [Bootable](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest) USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

I would see if there is an option in your BIOS to force the boot from your CD.  Try burning another CD / DVD.  The other option is to take a look at WUBI to see if it fits your needs.  It does not repartion your drive.  It uses a virtual partition to run ubuntu from.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows